# App crashes when fragment changes before volley response

Tags: android, android-volley

I have bottom navigation view which has 3 fragments named Home, Notifications and Account. In Home fragment I am making volley post request that uses users last known location and on the basis of that it fetches response from the server. I want to know:

1. When I switch between the fragment before the volley response my app crashes and when I switch after response is complete there is no app crash.
2. Response from server is not showing when activity launches very first time.It shows when I switch between the fragments and come back to it again.

It is showing error log:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:138)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:385)
    at tiffino.app.com.Home$1.onResponse(Home.java:245)
    at tiffino.app.com.Home$1.onResponse(Home.java:240)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Home.java

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    TextView fragText;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mLocation;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    StringRequest stringRequest;
    public static final String TAG = "MyTag";
    private static final String URL = "https://google.com";

    public Home() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        fragText = view.findViewById(R.id.fragText);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && requestQueue != null){
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            requestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLocation != null) {
            String str1 = hereLocation(mLocation.getLatitude(),mLocation.getLongitude());
            fragText.setText(str1);
            sendLocation(str1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }

    private void sendLocation(final String str1) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name",str1);
                return map;
            }   
        };
        stringRequest.setTag(TAG);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private String hereLocation(double lat, double lon) {
        String city = "";
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = geo.getFromLocation(lat,lon,10);
            if(addresses.size()>0) {
                for (Address adr: addresses) {
                    if(adr.getLocality()!=null && adr.getLocality().length()>0) {
                        city = adr.getLocality();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return city;
    }
}
```

Please let me know why app is crashing.

**THANKS**

Comment: Kindly share your code

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably with the getActivity() in the onRespones. The fragment isn't attached now to getActivity due to the fact that you are in another fragment now.

You can do:

```
if(isAdded()) { 
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Hey,i have attached code please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Elisha it is working fine now app is not crashing on switching between fragments.

Comment: @Digvijay it only prevents the crash, but not displaying the `Toast` then.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have implemented this and it is showing Toast, why do you think so

Comment: @Digvijay can you make that this is the right answer. You asked why it is happening and I gave you the answer because of getActivity.

Answer (score 1):

letting the `Activity` implement the callback listeners is the most proper way to do it... because alike this one is always able to obtain the `Context` - no matter which `Fragment` is currently displayed.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Response.Listener, Response.ErrorListener {

    ...
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if(response != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}
```

to be called alike this (from within the `Fragment`):

```
new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, getActivity());
```

one could still pass that `String` back into the current `Fragment`, if required.

Comment: @Digvijay because it implements the callback listeners (alike this it's guaranteed the response will always be delivered - and can then be dispatched, as required).

Comment: @Digvijay the issue is that the fragment is detached from activity before the request is completed, thus making the context unavailable, so if you want to have the Toast displayed either way then you need to register the callback in your Activity.

Comment: What if i wrap Toast inside if condition like if(isAdded()), it is working fine for me.

Comment: @Digvijay then the response will be lost - and the request was made for no reason. it only prevents the crash, but does not deliver the response, at least not to something which depends on the `Context`. would assume, that the `Toast` is only something temporary there... and one could as well as let some other class implement those listeners and then register it at request time.

Comment: oh i see...now i am facing one issue that is when i  activate location after launching my app then in my fragment it doesn't fetch location,but when i go to other fragment and come back to it it detects location why so.

Comment: @Digvijay this has the same cause as the other issue; when letting the `Activity` implement it, instead of the `Fragment`, there would be no delay (there possibly isn't even real delay, but the updates only get visible later). basically, that `Activity` is always present, while the `Fragments` might temporarily not be attached to an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Although, You have not provided a piece of code. But generally I can tell you that you should take care of many things when you create a web request with some callback methods.
For example suppose you have the following piece of code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        mTextView.setText(response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Set the tag on the request.
stringRequest.setTag(TAG);

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

It really depend on the logic of your application but for example one option is to totally cancel the request when the user leaves the current fragment. Therefore you can write the following code in the `onStop()` of your fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onStop () {
    super.onStop();
    if (queue!= null) {
        queue.cancelAll(TAG);
    }
}
```

Another option is to check for fragment status before you try to make the changes since the user might have left the fragment when your callback method is being called:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (isResumed())
            {
                mTextView.setText(response);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (isResumed())
            {
                mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the code but  i have tried your solution it is still crashing my app. i have attached my code plz go through it and correct me where i m wrong.